# how to store value of the li tag in php and submit into database

Tags: php, html, tags

I'm beginner in PHP building a e-commerce website. I have an issue with product size. I want to store the value of product size when clicked on add to cart button. 
Using ul and li tag in html to show size range for front end I want to add product size into cart table.

Can I use name attribute in ul tag to store value and pass through the form?

Here is my code

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
   <div class="filter-box">
      <div class="widget size">
         <h6 class="widget-title">Size</h6>
         <div class="widget-desc">
            <div class="row">
               <ul style="display: contents;">
                  <li id="1"><a class="filter-size-box" href="#">XS</a></li>
                  <li id="2"><a class="filter-size-box" href="#">S</a></li>
                  <li id="3"><a class="filter-size-box" href="#">M</a></li>
                  <li id="4"><a class="filter-size-box" href="#">L</a></li>
                  <li id="5"><a class="filter-size-box" href="#">XL</a></li>
                  <li id="6"><a value="" class="filter-size-box" href="#">XXL</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

There's no attribute like "name" for ul/li tag. You shouldn't use ul for this, you should use  with

```
<form method="POST">
    <select name="sizes">
       <option value="1">XS</option>
       <option value="2">S</option>
    </select> 
</form>
```

Then when you submit the form(POST) in PHP you'll have access to the values with `$_POST['sizes']`

It can be coded with JS and CSS that the select will look and behave as it was list with UL. There are already some components that are done like this and you may use them.

Comment: i know that but check this image i given my screenshot of size range https://imgur.com/a6HDXzO

Comment: can u suggest me how i can do this with js and use into form

Answer (score -1):

You can add hidden input in the form in this case and then set the value of this input with the help of jquery on click on anchor link.

Comment: show me some example so i can move further with this

Comment: 1) Add hidden input inside of the form 2) Write a jquery click handler for the anchor links 3) Inside click handler, find the parent elements ID attribute 4) Put this id as a value of hidden input.

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="size">   where i kept this input tag below the ul tag

Comment: <script>
                                                   $("#sizelist").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this).parent();
    $this.addClass("select").siblings().removeClass("select");
    $("#sizevalue").val($this.data("value"));
}); </script>

Comment: <ul style="display: contents;" id="sizelist">
                                                    <li data-value="XS" value="XS"><a class="filter-size-box" href="#">XS</a></li>
                                                    <li data-value="S"><a class="filter-size-box" href="#">S</a></li>
                                                    <li data-value="M"><a class="filter-size-box" href="#">M</a></li>
 </ul>
<input id="sizevalue"  name="size" type="hidden" />

Comment: can u check this once

Comment: @Shivam What error you are facing exactly. Seems like working for me. Check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/codething/02q7zs3b/

Comment: i want to add the size into cart when i click submit add to cart.Product is added but size is not reflecting.

Comment: what can i do for pass the value into form

Comment: tell bro i need ur help

Answer (score -1):

You should have to find some CSS like checkbox and make design like your need . and then you can use "name" attribute

Comment: but client want this only, so i don't how to do it help bro

Comment: You should try something like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816293/style-radio-input-and-label-separately